# Proof for maths induction

Tags: induction

**prove**: $$ \sum_{r=1}^{n}[r^{2}+1](r!)=n[(n+1)!]$$ **for all** $n \in N$

**prove** $n=1$, $(1^2+1)(1!)$ = $1[(1+1)!]$

**assume true for** $n=k$, $(k^2+1)$$(k!)$= $k$$[(k+1)!]$

**I got to here** : $[k^{2}+1](k!)+[(k+1)^2+1](k+1)! = (k+1)[(k+2)!]$

Comment: Prove...what??...And what is $\;r\;$ , anyway?

Comment: r=1, its the bottom of the sigma sorry didn't explain it

Comment: my bad, i fixed it to what i have now

Comment: was what i did correct, i seem to have a problem every time i get to n=k+1 as it seems really hard to get them equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If
$$ \sum_{r=0}^{n}(r^{2}+1)r!=n(n+1)!$$
then
$$ \sum_{r=0}^{n+1}(r^{2}+1)r!=\sum_{r=0}^{n}(r^{2}+1)r!+((n+1)^2+1)(n+1)!=$$
$$=n(n+1)!+((n+1)^2+1)(n+1)!=$$
$$=(n+1)!(n+((n+1)^2+1))=$$
$$=(n+1)!(n+n^2+2n+1+1)=$$
$$=(n+1)!(n^2+3n+2)=$$
$$=(n+1)!(n+2)(n+1)=$$
$$=(n+1)(n+2)!$$

Comment: @luke Both terms in $n(n+1)! + [(n+1)^2 + 1](n+1)!$ have a factor of $(n+1)!$, which he factored out.

Answer (score 3):

The inductive step is:

$$\sum_{r=1}^{n+1}(r^2+1)r!=\sum_{r=1}^n(r^2+1)r!+\left[(n+1)^2+1\right](n+1)!\stackrel{\text{Ind. Step}}=$$

$$=n\color{red}{(n+1)!}+\left[(n+1)^2+1\right]\color{red}{(n+1)!}=\color{red}{(n+1)!}\left[n+(n+1)^2+1\right]=$$

$$=(n+1)!\left[(n+1)(n+2)\right]=(n+1)(n+2)!\;\ldots$$

Comment: @luke, factor out $\;(n+1)!\;$ as it multiplies both summands there...

Answer (score 1):

Let $P(n)$ be the statement. Your inductive hypothesis in induction is to *assume* that $P(n)$ is true for some arbitrary value $k, k\in\mathbb{N}$. So you *assume* that:

$$\sum_{r=1}^k (r^2 + 1)r! = k(k+1)!$$

and now you have to try and prove that $P(k+1)$ is true if $P(k)$ is true *i.e.* prove that

$$\sum_{r=1}^{k+1} (r^2 + 1)r! = (k+1)(k+2)!$$

*assuming* that $\sum_{r=1}^k (r^2 + 1)r! = k(k+1)!$.

To progress, split the sum up as following:

$$\sum_{r=1}^{k+1} f(r) = \sum_{r=1}^{k} f(r) + f(k+1) \implies \sum_{r=1}^{k+1} (r^2 + 1)r! = \underbrace{\sum_{r=1}^{k} (r^2 + 1)r!}_{*} + \Big((k+1)^2 + 1\Big)(k+1)!$$

Substitute the equality from your inductive hypothesis for (*)

Answer (score 0):

For n = 1 this clearly holds.
Now for inductive step $n-1 \to n$:
$$\sum_{r=1}^n (r^2+1)r! = \sum_{r=1}^{n-1} (r^2+1)r! + (n^2+1)n!$$
now assuming that the proposition holds for $n-1$ and substituting it for the sum we have:
$$ (n-1)n! + (n^2+1)n! = n!(n^2+n+1-1) = n(n+1)n! = (n+1)!n$$

Doesn't matter if you make the step $n \to n+1$ or $n-1 \to n$.